# Jquery Datepicker Working at one file but not the other

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have a problem using a Datepicker and I don't know why it won't work, because it's already working in another php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#ende").datepicker({
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        constrainInput: true
                        });
            });
        </script>
            <TR>    
                <TH ALIGN=RIGHT>Ende neu: </TH>
                <TD><INPUT ID='ende' name='ende' TYPE=text></TD>
            </TR>
```

How I said it works well at the first php file but now it won't and I don't know why, maybe someone has a quick tip for me, what I have forgotten, because I can't find any difference.

Comment: Check your browser console. Is an any there?

Comment: so you have this script on both pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working now, ill just tryed to insert

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> #nur wenn etwas schief geht-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">
```

which also is at the head.inc... 
dont know why it is not using it, 
but it works now

 and thx guys for your tipp of jquery requirement

Answer (score 0):

Please check in 'view source' whether the jquery.js is defined top of all the scripts in the second page...hope you know how to view browser error console.

Comment: Both pages have  require("head.inc"); where jquery.js is defined
they should use both the same :/ but ill check the browser console